# First order stochastic dominance: two equivalent definitions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, monotone-functions

Consider two random variables $X$ and $Y$. $X$ is said to precede $Y$ in first order stochastic dominance sense if $\mathbb{E}[v(X) ] \leq \mathbb{E}[v(Y) ]$ for every non-decreasing function $v: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ or, equivalently, if $ \forall x \in  \mathbb{R}: \mathbb{P}\left\{X \leq x\right\}\geq \mathbb{P}\left\{Y \leq x\right\}. $

I understand how the first definition implies the second one (choose $v:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: z \mapsto I_{]x, +\infty[}(z) $ for any $ x \in  \mathbb{R}$ fixed). However, I can't seem to figure out why they are equivalent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For nonnegative random variables, write $\nu$ as $$\nu(x)=\nu(0)+\int_0^xd\mu(y)$$ for every nonnegative $x$, for some nonnegative measure $\mu$ and use the identity $$E(\nu(X))=\nu(0)+\int_0^\infty P(X>x)d\mu(x)$$ twice. Then extend the result to real valued random variables.

Comment: How do I extend this to real valued random variables?

Comment: *Show what you tried*.

Comment: I wrote $ X = max\{X,0\} - max\{-X,0\}$ so $v(X) = v(max\{X,0\} - max\{-X,0\})$. Can I exploit the monotonicity of $v $ to rewrite this in a way such that I can apply the positive variable case?